# What is wrong with this Model?

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

Perhaps it is a simple answer but I tried a lot of things without success. The problem is that my "PropertyChange" is always null in spite _gauges have values as picture at annex. UPDATE - I added more code (WpfControl is where WindowsFormsHost is defined. MyControl is the "Form" that is hosted at my WPF App

**StackPanel**

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:WpfControl Width="500" GaugesStatus="{Binding Gauge}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            
            public static readonly ViewModel instanceRet = new ViewModel();
            public ViewModel()
            { 
            }
    
            public static ViewModel InstanceRet => instanceRet;
                           
            private Gauges _gauges;
            public Gauges Gauge
            {
                get { return _gauges; }
                set
                {
                    _gauges = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Gauge");
                }
            }
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
```

**Code behind**

```
 public test()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();

    if (AltAircraft.Text != "AltAircraft")
    {
        Gauges gauge = new Gauges();
        gauge = new Gauges 
            { 
             Altitude = Convert.ToDouble(AltAircraft.Text), 
             AirSpeed = zSpeedKTS, 
             Heading = headingToWp, 
             PitchAngle = 0.123, 
             RollAngle = 0, TurnRate = 0 
            };
         ViewModel.InstanceRet.Gauge=gauge;
    }
    
 public class Gauges
 {
       public double  TurnRate { get; set; }
       public double  Altitude { get; set; }
       public double  RollAngle { get; set; }
       public double  PitchAngle { get; set; }
       public double  VerticalSpeed { get; set; }
       public double  Heading { get; set; }
       public double  AirSpeed { get; set; }
 }
```

**WpfControl**

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Testminimums.WpfControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMinimums"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600">
        
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="MyHost">
            <local:MyControl />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
        
    </UserControl>
```

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [mcve] - I realise with WPF that will be larger than (say) with a console app, but it's going to be hard to help you without it. (I now see you're setting the data context in your unconventionally-named `test` constructor, but it's still hard to disentangle everything. Having a singleton ViewModel is almost certainly not helping, either... and may be the cause of the problem, given that the `Gauge` property you're changing isn't the one on your DataContext.)

Comment: DataContext and ViewModel.InstanceRet are two different Instances of the ViewModel class. Are you confused by having two of them?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, my code has thousand of lines so I am not seeing a way to reproduce it. Alias it needs a flight simulator server to get the values I am trying to bind. Thks anyway

Comment: "Hi @JonSkeet, my code has thousand of lines so I am not seeing a way to reproduce it." Keep removing code until you're left with just the bare minimum, or start from scratch and add code until you can reproduce the problem. Just because the original project is large is no justification for not providing a minimal repro.

Comment: Hi @Ralf, perhaps you are correct but I have another ViewModel with this logic and it works without problem. I will try to remove one of the instances

Comment: @JonSkeet, you are right. Anyway I must evaluate if it is possible to do that in few  in few minutes

Comment: Hi @Ralf, I removed the ViewModel.InstanceRet! Now is vm.Gauge=gauge with vm being an instance of ViewModel  but the property is still null.

Comment: I will try to isolate this with a new Project as @JonSkeet suggested.

Comment: @LuisNovaisReis: No, the *property* (`Gauge`) isn't null, the `PropertyChanged` *event* is null, i.e. nothing has subscribed to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure with only bits and pieces of code, but I strongly suspect the problem is that you've got two different `ViewModel` instances:

- The one you're setting as the `DataContext` (`DataContext = new ViewModel();`)
- The semi-singleton one accessed as `ViewModel.InstanceRet`

I would strongly advise getting rid of `InstanceRet` entirely - it feels like it's asking for trouble. Instead, just change your `test` constructor to:

```cs
public test()
{
    InitializeComponent();
          
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;

    if (AltAircraft.Text != "AltAircraft")
    {
        // Note: I've no idea where this data will come from, given
        // that we're in a constructor...
        Gauges gauge = new Gauges
        {
            Altitude = Convert.ToDouble(AltAircraft.Text),
            AirSpeed = zSpeedKTS,
            Heading = headingToWp,
            PitchAngle = 0.123,
            RollAngle = 0,
            TurnRate = 0
        };
        vm.Gauge = gauge;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewModel` instance used by your control as the `DataContext` i.e. binding source is not the same instance that you modify in the `test()` constructor. You set the `Gauge` property on the static instance that is not used by the UI for data binding, therefore there is no listener for the `PropertyChanged` event of this static instance.

Why would you create a static instance of the `ViewModel` in the first place? You should create an instance and pass it (the same instance!) around your application where it is needed. Introducing a static instance also introduces some serious limitations and problems. You should avoid doing this in general.

If you really believe you need to share an instance by making it static, then at least make sure to use it exclusively. This means, don't crate an instance of `ViewModel` explicitly. For this reason, the constructor of `ViewModel` must be `private`. The field `instanceRet` should also be `private`:

```cs
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{            
  private static readonly ViewModel instanceRet = new ViewModel();
 
  // Enforce the use of the static instance
  // by defining the constructor private.
  private ViewModel()
  { 
  }
    
  public static ViewModel InstanceRet
  {
    get
    {
      return instanceRet;
    }
  }
           
  private Gauges _gauges;
  public Gauges Gauge
  {
    get { return _gauges; }
    set
    {
      _gauges = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Gauge");
    }
  }
    
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;    
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)    
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Example**

```cs
public test()
{
  InitializeComponent();
          
  DataContext = ViewModel.InstanceRet;

  if (AltAircraft.Text != "AltAircraft")
  {
    Gauges gauge = new Gauges();
    gauge = new Gauges { Altitude = Convert.ToDouble(AltAircraft.Text), AirSpeed = zSpeedKTS, Heading = headingToWp, PitchAngle = 0.123, RollAngle = 0, TurnRate = 0 };
    ViewModel.InstanceRet.Gauge = gauge;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @BionicCode , you saved my day. It works perfectly. I was struggling with this for several days.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet as I was working at a reproducible example to all of you i did not see your answers. Only the last answer was visible at my screenone of was visible and it works like a charm.